# How To Capture Using Regex In VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to capture `dal.socks.ipvanish.com` using regex in vb.net from the given source.

```
</td>
 <td class="StatTDLabel">Dallas</td>
 <td class="StatTDLabel">dal.socks.ipvanish.com</td>
</tr>
```

Here is my piece of code but that's not working I don't know why can anybody help me to figure it out.

```
Dim str1 As Match = Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text, "<td class=""StatTDLabel"">(.*?)<\/td>\n                    <\/tr>")

TextBox2.Text = str1.Groups(1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

See the regex explanation here:
https://regex101.com/r/pJAD31/1

Basically you have to match the second occurrence of `StatTDLabel">` as your input string is having two occurrences of the same.

See the working code here https://dotnetfiddle.net/W9lbVH

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
                
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        
        Dim pattern As String = "StatTDLabel"">.*?(StatTDLabel"">)(.*)<\/td>"
        Dim input As String = "</td> <td class=""StatTDLabel"">Dallas</td> <td class=""StatTDLabel"">dal.socks.ipvanish.com</td> </tr>"
        Dim options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline
        Dim Match = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options)
    
        Console.WriteLine (Match(0).Groups(2))
        
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: actual source looks like this

Comment: @M_Hashir, what do you mean by "actual source looks like this"

Comment: sorry I was able to provide source cuz it was long enough. The problem is that there is a new line in the source but when I use \n it works in Regex.com but not working in VB.net

Comment: @M_Hashir If my answer has solved your problem then mark it as answer or let me know here if you still have any issue

Comment: my problem was solved but not with your method maybe it was my fault I couldn't explain my problem properly but thanks for your efforts